# How to resolve Pandas performance warning "highly fragmented" after using many custom np.where statements?

Tags: python, pandas, copy, concatenation, where-clause

I have a project where I am converting code from SQL to Pandas. I have 80 custom elements in my dataset / dataframe - each requires custom logic. In SQL, I use multiple case statements within a single Select like this:

```
Select x, y, z,
(case when statement1 then 0
when statement2 then 0
else 1 end) as custom_element1,
next case statement...as custom_element2,
next case statement...as custom_element3,
etc...
```

Now in Pandas, I am hoping for some advice on the most efficient way to accomplish the same goal. To make it easier to reproduce, here is an example that does the same thing that I want to do. I need to create 80 custom output variables. In this example, I am just adding one custom element at a time using different np.where statements.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0]},
                   index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
df['custom1'] = np.where(df['num_legs'].values > 2, 1, 0)
df['custom2'] = np.where(df['num_wings'] == df['num_legs'], 1, 0)
df['custom3'] = np.where((df['num_wings'].values == 0) | (df['num_legs'].values == 0), 1, 0)
```

I can get the output from consecutive np.where statements to match my output from original SQL exactly, so no problems there.

BUT I saw this warning:

```
DataFrame is highly fragmented...poor performance...Consider using pd.concat 
instead...or use copy().
```

So my question is, for my example, how do I improve performance? How would I use pd.concat here? What is a better way to structure the code than what I am showing above? I have tried searching for an answer in this forum but did not find anything. I appreciate your time in responding.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what you are doing? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Almost certainly, you should just be using an entirely different approach. in any case, again, you really must provide specific details about what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for looking at this...I provided a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks much @juanpa.arrivilaga!!! This is exactly what I needed and I can use this directly.

Answer (score 0):

So, `np.where` is totally unecessary here. For example, you can just use:

```
In [6]: df.num_legs > 2
Out[6]:
falcon    False
dog        True
spider     True
fish      False
Name: num_legs, dtype: bool
```

Instead of:

```
In [9]: np.where(df.num_legs > 2, 1, 0)
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

These probably *should* be bool dtype columns, but if you insist on using int, just add an `.astype(int)`.

In any case, here is how you might use `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        (df["num_legs"] > 2).rename("custom1"),
        (df["num_wings"] == df["num_legs"]).rename("custom1"),
        ((df["num_wings"] == 0) | (df["num_legs"] == 0)).rename("custom3"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Example:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
        num_legs  num_wings
falcon         2          2
dog            4          0
spider         8          0
fish           0          0

In [11]: pd.concat(
    ...:     [
    ...:         df,
    ...:         (df["num_legs"] > 2).rename("custom1"),
    ...:         (df["num_wings"] == df["num_legs"]).rename("custom1"),
    ...:         ((df["num_wings"] == 0) | (df["num_legs"] == 0)).rename("custom3"),
    ...:     ],
    ...:     axis=1,
    ...: )
Out[11]:
        num_legs  num_wings  custom1  custom1  custom3
falcon         2          2    False     True    False
dog            4          0     True    False     True
spider         8          0     True    False     True
fish           0          0    False     True     True
```